# django | display the name value from select option with ajax (jquery) not the id

Tags: python, json, django, ajax

**this is the ajax code**

```
    $('.addtasksubmit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        

        $.ajax({
            url: 'addtodo',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                title: $('#task-title').val(),
                category: $('#catsel option:selected').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                $('.todos-box').append(`
                  <a href="#" class="category-link">${response.category}</a>
                `)
                $("#addtodo").trigger('reset');
                $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
            }
        })
    })
```

##### **So** ${response.category} gives me the id of the category but i need the category name to be viewed

and this is views.py

```
        response = {
        'title': request.POST['title'],
        'category' : request.POST['category'],
        }
        todo = Todo.objects.create(title=response['title'],
                                     category=Category.objects.get(id=response['category']),
                                     user=request.user)   
        todo.save()
   return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

this is HTML

```
<select name="category" class="form-select form-select-sm" id="catsel">
            <option seleted>Choose Category</option>
            {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
</select>
```

#### is there any way to view the category name with ajax not the id? or how can i get the name of the category with its id.

sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **so i have solved this problem after 5 days of trying.**

added this to the views

```
        response['category']=Category.objects.filter(id=category)
                           .values('name').first()
        data = json.dumps(response)
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

and ajax

```
                <div class="category-list flex-1">
                  <a href="#" class="category-link">${response['category'].name}</a>
                </div>
```

and also added `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to get the HTML select input with the categories from the template. Based on what you posted please adjust the views.py to

```
  todo = Todo.objects.create(title=response['title'],
  category = Category.objects.get(id=response['category']),
                                 user=request.user)   
  todo.save()  

  response = {
      'title': request.POST['title'],
      'category' : category.name,
  }


return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```